# Adding separators to a TreeView only after top level items in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

My TreeView ends up looking like this.

```
+ level 1
- level 2
   + level 2.1
   + level 2.2  
+ level 3
```

My requirement is to display a separator only after top level items like this:

```
+ level 1
  ----------
- level 2
   + level 2.1
   + level 2.2
  -----------  
+ level 3
```

I referred to this existing question [WPF TreeView Style with Seperator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726660/wpf-treeview-style-with-seperator) , But when I implemented, I observed that the separators are seen very stretched and get added after every level which i don't want.

Here is my TreeView code:

```
 <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonViewModelList}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" DataType="{x:Type local:PersonViewModel}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountryType}" FontWeight="Bold"/>                                                      
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: There are no separators in your current code. Why don't you provide what you have done so far ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think what I have presented in my question is already a minimal reproducible example. I didn't wanted to confuse everyone by posting the complete style which is already there in the link provided in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a separator element to your `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, e.g.:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonViewModelList}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Names}" DataType="{x:Type local:PersonViewModel}">
            <DockPanel>
                <Border BorderThickness="1,0,1,1"
                                Height="1"
                                Width="{Binding ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}"
                                DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <DrawingBrush Viewport="0,0,8,8" ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile">
                            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                <DrawingGroup>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="Silver">
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <GeometryGroup>
                                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50" />
                                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,50,50,50" />
                                            </GeometryGroup>
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                </DrawingGroup>
                            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        </DrawingBrush>
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                </Border>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountryType}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```